# moveToElement function not working on IE when browser is minimized or not active using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium2, webdriver

I'm trying to automate an application using Selenium Webdriver.  The moveToElement function fails when the browser is minimized or not active (keep other app active). It works when I keep AUT browser as the active window.

My code:

```
menu=driver.findElement(By.xpath(OwnerName));
builder.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
```

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.Exception: //div[contains(@class,'profileCardBtnsContainer')]//dt[text()='Actions'] is not found on the page with in the time period
 [java]     at main.java.com.ca.saas.UXMedia.utils.Globals.waitForElementPresent(Globals.java:191)
 [java]     at main.java.com.ca.saas.UXMedia.utils.ChatUtils.initiatingChatFromDeviceList(ChatUtils.java:258)
 [java]     at main.java.com.ca.saas.UXMedia.Tests.ChatTests.verifyChatFromDevices(ChatTests.java:1031)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:76)
 [java]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
 [java]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:846)
 [java]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1170)
 [java]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
 [java]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
 [java]     at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1147)
 [java]     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
 [java]     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
 [java]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
 [java]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:312)
 [java]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:274)
 [java]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:223)
 [java]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 [java]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
 [java]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1039)
 [java]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:964)
 [java]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:900)
 [java]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1182)
 [java]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1146)
```

Comment: I do not expect Webdriver to work when the brower is minimized.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here... Yes your assertion is correct WebDriver doesn't work properly when the browser is minimised.  This is because it uses native events to click on the browser rather than just emulating clicks with JavaScript so if it isn't there to click on the clicks don't work.

Answer (score 3):

WebDriver does not work properly when the browser is minimized.

Comment: if web driver is openig multiple browsers, can you close them after x seconds?