# Running WebDriver without opening actual browser window

Tags: selenium2, webdriver

I've heard rumors that Selenium WebDriver can run without opening a real browser window, meaning it runs in the background.  I am using the C# Client Drivers, FirefoxDriver within the automated tests, and launching a class library project (containing my code) using NUnit.

- If so, how can this be done?
- Also, what is the benefit to doing it this way?
- Do you still have to keep the waits (thread.sleep and implicit waits) in the code since the browser isn't open?

Comment: Related: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2538/movetoelement-function-not-working-on-ie-when-browser-is-minimized-or-not-active

Comment: You can use headless browser for that. Such as PhantomJS, HtmlUnitDriver etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One option is HTMLUnit, which is headless but has its own proprietary JavaScript rendering engine, so it is possible that it will behave differently than existing browsers (If you do use HTMLUnit, don't forget to enable JavaScript when you instantiate it).

The second option is to use XVFB; this will run the tests in a virtual frame buffer environemt.  This has been reported quite a few times on the Selenium users mailing list as well as the Selenium blog, [see this post](http://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/a-smattering-of-selenium-76/) for some XVFB implementations.

Linking directly to the tutorials:

1. [functional-headless-ui-testing-django-selenium](http://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2015/03/02/functional-headless-ui-testing-django-selenium/)
2. [Watch player_embedded](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=DL7gyuqkzzU)

If you google for Selenium and XVFB you'll find lots more info.

Comment: looks like some of these links broke

Comment: Main site:  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins

Comment: XVFB: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin

Comment: `from pyvirtualdisplay import Display  # xvfb wrapper; display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600)); display.start()`

Answer (score 16):

It is quite easy to hide the browser without XVFB. Just [install PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html). Then, change this line:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

to:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

The rest of your code won't need to be changed and no browser will open. For debugging purposes, use `driver.save_screenshot('screen.png')` at different steps of your code.

Comment: is it the same for Chrome tests?

Comment: But if you have javascript you may have issues.  If you use Chrome you may have cross-browser scripting issues.  @nexoma's answer might address this but not sure what the deal is with javascript for chrome headless.

Comment: I believe PhantomJS has JS in its name for a reason; it perfectly handles Javascript – Not sure why Chrome is being mentioned here

Answer (score 11):

You used to be able to use PhantomJS for this, but since PhantomJS itself is discontinued, so is the Selenium PhantomJS driver.

The good news is, that you can simply use Chrome. Chrome itself has gotten the feature of [being able to run without an actual browser window](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

So after instantiating your chrome driver, you can simply add instructions to work headless

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.add_argument('headless');
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600'); // optional
```

[source](https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/)

Answer (score 4):

You can attempt to run your tests inside an instance of the HtmlUnitDriver.  I attempted to look at the documentation on this, but the chm file inside of the latest release seems to be botched.

There is also [WebkitDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webkitdriver/), but that seems to be Java only for the time being.

Comment: Reminder: if you use HtmlUnitDriver, there is no guarantee the same tests will actually work in a real browser.

Comment: I read on the WebDriver wiki today that HTMLUnitDriver only works with the Java client drivers, so I won't be able to use this approach, since we use the C# client drivers.  :-\  But I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 4):

You can RUN the Test using HTMLUnitDriver, its the fastest and light weight of most of webdrivers

Comment: We use the C# drivers and NUnit, so I would have to re-write everything in Java, wouldn't I?

Comment: The syntax changes from language to language, but the Logic what you are trying to test remains the same

Comment: @MacGyver: No, you don't have to switch the language, think of HTMLUnit as the browser that is started, not as a testing framework. It does not matter for you in what language it was written, like it does not matter for firefox etc. At the very minimum you can always start the selenium server and connect to it using the webdriver bindings, specifying you want HTMLUnit. In C#: `IWebDriver drive = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());` There might be also a HTMLUnitDriver (for connecting directly) in the C# bindings, as C# belongs to the four officially supported languages.

Answer (score 3):

simply use the below code to run your current chosen browser as a headless browser, headless browser means that it will not open a browser when you run your code.

```
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

We need to import atleast the following packages:

```
from selenium import webdriver   # for webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
```

In the program:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver',options=option)
```

Then simply continue your task as usual.